# Unable to access JavaScript Object property from CSV file

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties

I am having a hard time figuring out how to access a property of my javascript object.

I have a Node JS application that downloads a CSV file from the WHO with covid data and then I loop through each of these entries. Here is how I loop through each of the CSV entries:

```
fs.createReadStream("data.csv")
.pipe(csv())
.on("data", (data) => {
  //process data 
})
.on("end", () => {
});
```

Here is one sample of the output when I run `console.log(data)`

```
{                                                                         
  '﻿Name': 'Niger',                                                       
  'WHO Region': 'Africa',                                                 
  'Cases - cumulative total': '6203',                                     
  'Cases - cumulative total per 100000 population': '25.63',              
  'Cases - newly reported in last 7 days': '64',                          
  'Cases - newly reported in last 7 days per 100000 population': '0.26',  
  'Cases - newly reported in last 24 hours': '10',                        
  'Deaths - cumulative total': '205',                                     
  'Deaths - cumulative total per 100000 population': '0.85',              
  'Deaths - newly reported in last 7 days': '1',                          
  'Deaths - newly reported in last 7 days per 100000 population': '0',    
  'Deaths - newly reported in last 24 hours': '0'                         
}
```

If I run `typeof data` I am getting `object`.

I would like to access some properties of this object.
If I output `data["WHO Region"]` I get "Africa". So this works.

---

However, I am unable to access the name of those object.

```
console.log(data["Name"]);
console.log(data.hasOwnProperty("Name"));
```

Outputs respectively `undefined` and `false`

Even though the name property is present within the object.

---

I have also tried to list the keys of the object with Object.keys(data) and here is the result:

```
 [ 'Name', 'WHO Region', 'Cases - cumulative total', ... ]
```

So apparently the key Name does exist but I can't access it for some reason.
Am I missing something there?

Comment: Do you have an example of CSV file? Just for clarification.

Comment: @koloml It's the CSV file from that page https://covid19.who.int/table/
Here is the download link: https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv

Comment: Check the answer. This file have single character at the start of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file, represented by the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` corresponding to the UTF-8 codepoint [U+FEFF](https://codepoints.net/U+FEFF).

[image]

An easy workaround for your code would be to replace this like so:

```
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => {
    // Replace BOM in key
    const key1 = Object.keys(data)[0];
    data = { ...data, [key1.replace(/\uFEFF/, '')]: data[key1] };
    results.push(data);
})
.on('end', () => {
    results.forEach(result => { 
        console.log(`Name: ${result["Name"]}`);
    })
});
```

*or*

You could open the file in Nodepad++ and using the `Encoding` menu change it from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8 and saving.

Answer (score 2):

You have invisible symbol in the `Name` property of the object. You can see it if you past result of the `console.log` in the browser console:

[image: Output from Chrome DevTools]

Check your original CSV file and search for this invisible character.

**EDIT:** This symbol is [ZWNBSP (Zero Width No-Break Space)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FEFF) at the start of the file.

[image: ZWNBSP character visible in IDE]

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I didn't know about that symbol